Constructing independent identical random variables on $([0,1], \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]},m)$
Let the probability space be $([0,1], \mathcal{B},m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Question 1: Construct a sequence of random variables, $\{X_i\}$ such that (i) each $X_i$ takes values 0 and 1 with equal probabilities and (ii) $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent for $i \neq j$.
My solution: Let $A_{i,n} = \left[\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i+1}{2^n}\right)$. Define $$X_n = \sum_{i=0}^{2^{2i-1} - 1} \mathbf{1}_{A_{2j, 2i}} $$
Then each $X_i$ is a Ber($1/2$) random variable, and all of them are independent.
Question 2: Using $\{X_i\}$, define $Y = \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{X_{2i}}{2^i}$. Find the distribution of Y.
Here I am stuck, and don't know how to proceed. I tried manually writing out a few $X_i$'s to try and understand how $Y$ behaves, but I can't seem to get anywhere with that.
Question 3: Define $Z = \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{X_{2i-1}}{2^i}$. Show that Y and Z are independent and identically distributed.
Again, I don't really understand how these random variables are supposed to look, and don't know how to start working out their independence.
Any help is appreciated.

I like this one ... write $x \in [0,1)$ in base $2$ as $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k(x) 2^{-k}$.  Then use $X_k = r_k$.  Due to Borel, around 1910, I think.
